# Swinject: Resolution failed when using multiple modules (projects) in workspace

Tags: ios, swift, swinject

I am trying to setup DI for multi-module workspace with Swinject. I have one `ParentProject` where I embed binary framework built from `ChildProject` (so `ParentProject` includes all public code from `ChildProject`).

My approach is to create one Assembly for each module, and assemble them together in ParentProject. The errors I am getting are really weird to me, take one for `NSPersistentContainer`:

`Swinject: Resolution failed. Expected registration:
    { Service: NSPersistentContainer, Factory: Resolver -> NSPersistentContainer }
Available registrations:
    { Service: NSPersistentContainer, Factory: Resolver -> NSPersistentContainer, ObjectScope: container }`

Example of Assembly from ParentProject:

`public class ParentProjectAssembly: Assembly {
    ...
    public func assemble(container: Container) {
        ...
        container.register(NSPersistentContainer.self) { _ in
            return self.persistentContainer
            }.inObjectScope(.container)
        ...
    }
}`

It doesn't really matter if I move this registration code to the `ChildProjectAssembly` or I have this registration in both of them, error is always the same. My assembler is just `Assembler([ParentProjectAssembly(), ChildProjectAssembly()]` in ParentProject's AppDelegate (for now). It seems that everything works fine, `assemble(container:)` method has the same container for all of the assemblies, some injections do work, but others have this error suggesting that I should register service without specifying objectScope at all? That isn't possible.

Help

Comment: Are you by any chance using Swift PM producing static lib? If so, see https://github.com/Swinject/Swinject/issues/425

Comment: Sadly no, I am just using Cocoapods to install external libs into the projects in the workspace.